# How to view enumerator in opencv methods from source code?

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

[image]

I want to find the enumeration type constants of the keyword parameters of a specific method in the source code of OpenCV-python. For example, "interpolation" in cv2. resize() can be easily found by clicking "interpolationflags" on the official website, but it seems that "interpolationflags" can not be found in the source code.

Comment: please post code/text as code or text, not as images

Comment: Likely not.  OpenCV is a C++ library,  The Python module is just a wrapper around that C++ library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/0c01cf7c85dec1c0e558892330d949994593a5b9/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp#L245)

```
enum InterpolationFlags{
    /** nearest neighbor interpolation */
    INTER_NEAREST        = 0,
    /** bilinear interpolation */
    INTER_LINEAR         = 1,
    /** bicubic interpolation */
    INTER_CUBIC          = 2,
    /* resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire-free results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST  method. */
    INTER_AREA           = 3,
    /** Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 neighborhood */
    INTER_LANCZOS4       = 4,
    /** Bit exact bilinear interpolation */
    INTER_LINEAR_EXACT = 5,
    /** Bit exact nearest neighbor interpolation. This will produce same results as
    the nearest neighbor method in PIL, scikit-image or Matlab. */
    INTER_NEAREST_EXACT  = 6,
    /** mask for interpolation codes */
    INTER_MAX            = 7,
    /** flag, fills all of the destination image pixels. If some of them correspond to outliers in the
    source image, they are set to zero */
    WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS   = 8,
    /** flag, inverse transformation
    For example, #linearPolar or #logPolar transforms:
    - flag is __not__ set: \f$dst( \rho , \phi ) = src(x,y)\f$
    - flag is set: \f$dst(x,y) = src( \rho , \phi )\f$
    */
    WARP_INVERSE_MAP     = 16
};
```

Comment: I probably understand.....it means opencv-python cannt view it in python source code?

Comment: right, it is C++ code, it won't be visible in Python